# Warning: Attempt to present when segueing from table view

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am really struggling with a simple modal segue between scenes, the code is a follows in the originating scene:

*I found the answer - I was segueing from a cell and not the view. Thought my experience might be useful to anyone with similar problems*

```
// MARK:  UITableViewDelegate Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
       key1 = catRet[indexPath.row - 1]
        println(indexPath.row)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToSubActivities", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "goToSubActivities") {
            let nav2 = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let svc2 = nav2.topViewController as! ActivityFormTableViewController
            svc2.dataPassed2 = key1
            println(svc2.dataPassed2)
        }
    }
```

and then in the recipient code as follows:

```
@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
    var dataPassed2:String!
    var catRet2 = XnYCategories.mainCats("Sport")
    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell2"
    //var activityDictionary = [String : [String]]()
    var passData: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(dataPassed2)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        }
```

The dataPassed2 does not appear in the recipient and I get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - I was segueing from a cell and not the view. Thought my experience might be useful to anyone with similar problems.

As simple as that!